# I am getting following error , when I am running a JBOSS server?

Tags: jboss, redhat-satellite

I am Installed Jboss in my machine. But, While I am running I am getting following issue.

```
10:36:15,667 ERROR [org.jboss.as.process.Server:IDMDomain.status] (ProcessController-threads - 3) JBAS012006: Failed to send data bytes to process 'Server:IDMDomain' input stream: java.io.IOException: **Stream closed**
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:434) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
        at org.jboss.as.process.stdin.BaseNCodecOutputStream.flush(BaseNCodecOutputStream.java:125) [jboss-as-process-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.process.stdin.BaseNCodecOutputStream.flush(BaseNCodecOutputStream.java:137) [jboss-as-process-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.process.stdin.Base64OutputStream.flush(Base64OutputStream.java:44) [jboss-as-process-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.process.stdin.BaseNCodecOutputStream.close(BaseNCodecOutputStream.java:154) [jboss-as-process-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.process.stdin.Base64OutputStream.close(Base64OutputStream.java:44) [jboss-as-process-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.process.ManagedProcess.sendStdin(ManagedProcess.java:164) [jboss-as-process-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.process.ProcessController.sendStdin(ProcessController.java:207) [jboss-as-process-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.process.ProcessControllerServerHandler$InitMessageHandler$ConnectedMessageHandler.handleMessage(ProcessControllerServerHandler.java:140) [jboss-as-process-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.process.protocol.ConnectionImpl.safeHandleMessage(ConnectionImpl.java:269) [jboss-as-process-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.process.protocol.ConnectionImpl$1$1.run(ConnectionImpl.java:223) [jboss-as-process-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
```

Any one can help me to rectify this issue.